# Twilio - Using JavaScript?

Tags: twilio

So I have created a couple of sms apps with PHP but looking to create one that will call on Google Maps API to determine if an address is within a polygon.

How would I take a response from JavaScript and then output to twilio response. My PHP responses usually look like:

`header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
    ?>
    <Response>
        <Message><?php echo $message; ?></Message>
    </Response>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

twilio developer evangelist here.

Gonna make the assumption you have access to NodeJS.

That being the case you can just use the [Node Helper Library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install) by running:

```
npm install -g twilio
```

All you have to do then is use the library like this:

```
var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
twiml.message('Hi!  Thanks for checking out my app!');
```

Don't forget to set the encoding to XML.

A full express app would look something like this:

```
var twilio = require('twilio'),
    express = require('express');

// Create express app with middleware to parse POST body
var app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded());

// Create a route to respond to a call
app.post('/respond', function(req, res) {
    //Validate that this request really came from Twilio...
    if (twilio.validateExpressRequest(req, 'YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN')) {
        var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();

        twiml.message('Hi!  Thanks for checking out my app!');

        res.type('text/xml');
        res.send(twiml.toString());
    }
    else {
        res.send('you are not twilio.');
    }
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```